# Can ONE setblock command set multiple blocks, each in different locations?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

```
/setblock -19 4 11, -19 4 15, -12 4 12 lit_redstone_lamp
```

Like that? I tried, doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

No, each `/setblock` command can only set one block at a time. You can place command blocks in a command chain instead, or run one command at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place more then a single block at once with setblock but you can use `/clone <source corner 1> <source corner 2> <destination (north-west corner)>` instead and copy an entire building and place it anywhere you want.

Comment: I think you’ve gotten the syntax for `/clone` wrong. The source coordinates come *before* the destination, not after.

Comment: Yes, it should be `<source corner 1> <source corner 2> <destination (south-west corner)>`

Answer (score 0):

No, but using the /fill command will fill multiple blocks at once.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/297672)

Comment: @KyleRone the question was: *Can one setblock command place multiple blocks?* And the first word in this answer was "no". While maybe this wasn't the best post, "no" is definitely an answer, not a comment. To @John maybe go into the syntax of `/fill` to make a better answer.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i know, but this is their post so won't they still be notified, or does it not notify them then? I'll do it anyway

Comment: @John maybe go into the syntax of `/fill` to make a better answer.